# Hive create table failed

Tags: mysql, hive

```
hive> create table employee( eid  int, name string, salary string, destination string) row format delimited fields terminated by ',';
```

Error Stack:

```
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. MetaException(message:An exception was thrown while adding/validating class(es) : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[CHARACTER SET charset_name] [COLLATE collation_name] NULL,
    `VIEW_ORIGINAL_T' at line 12
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[CHARACTER SET charset_name] [COLLATE collation_name] NULL,
    `VIEW_ORIGINAL_T' at line 12
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:118)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:95)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:790)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:675)
        at com.jolbox.bonecp.StatementHandle.execute(StatementHandle.java:254)
        at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.table.AbstractTable.executeDdlStatement(AbstractTable.java:879)
        at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.table.AbstractTable.executeDdlStatementList(AbstractTable.java:830)
        at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.table.AbstractTable.create(AbstractTable.java:546)
        at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.table.AbstractTable.exists(AbstractTable.java:609)
        at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager$ClassAdder.performTablesValidation(RDBMSStoreManager.java:3365)
        at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager$ClassAdder.run(RDBMSStoreManager.java:2877)
        at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.AbstractSchemaTransaction.execute(AbstractSchemaTransaction.java:119)
        at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager.manageClasses(RDBMSStoreManager.java:1608)
        at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager.getDatastoreClass(RDBMSStoreManager.java:671)
        at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager.getPropertiesForGenerator(RDBMSStoreManager.java:2069)
        at org.datanucleus.store.AbstractStoreManager.getStrategyValue(AbstractStoreManager.java:1271)
        at org.datanucleus.ExecutionContextImpl.newObjectId(ExecutionContextImpl.java:3759)
        at org.datanucleus.state.StateManagerImpl.setIdentity(StateManagerImpl.java:2267)
        at org.datanucleus.state.StateManagerImpl.initialiseForPersistentNew(StateManagerImpl.java:484)
        at org.datanucleus.state.StateManagerImpl.initialiseForPersistentNew(StateManagerImpl.java:120)
        at org.datanucleus.state.ObjectProviderFactoryImpl.newForPersistentNew(ObjectProviderFactoryImpl.java:218)
        at org.datanucleus.ExecutionContextImpl.persistObjectInternal(ExecutionContextImpl.java:2078)
        at org.datanucleus.ExecutionContextImpl.persistObjectWork(ExecutionContextImpl.java:1922)
        at org.datanucleus.ExecutionContextImpl.persistObject(ExecutionContextImpl.java:1777)
        at org.datanucleus.ExecutionContextThreadedImpl.persistObject(ExecutionContextThreadedImpl.java:217)
        at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.jdoMakePersistent(JDOPersistenceManager.java:715)
        at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.makePersistent(JDOPersistenceManager.java:740)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.createTable(ObjectStore.java:1025)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.invoke(RawStoreProxy.java:101)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy27.createTable(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.create_table_core(HiveMetaStore.java:1440)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.create_table_with_environment_context(HiveMetaStore.java:1484)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.invokeInternal(RetryingHMSHandler.java:148)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.invoke(RetryingHMSHandler.java:107)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy35.create_table_with_environment_context(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.create_table_with_environment_context(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:2364)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.create_table_with_environment_context(SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.java:93)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.createTable(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:748)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.createTable(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:736)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.invoke(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:173)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy36.createTable(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createTable(Hive.java:848)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createTable(Hive.java:863)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.createTable(DDLTask.java:4153)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.execute(DDLTask.java:342)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task.executeTask(Task.java:197)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner.runSequential(TaskRunner.java:100)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.launchTask(Driver.java:2084)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.execute(Driver.java:1755)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1463)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1181)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1171)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:233)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:184)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:403)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:821)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:759)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:686)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)


Mysql version is:Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.20, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
Hive Version is:2.2.0
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems CHARACTER SET is not set for your "metastore" database in MySQL. Login into MySQL using "root" user and then run the below SQL. Here you have to mention your "metastore_db_name" which is configured in "hive-site.xml". Here I am suggesting the standard character set, but if you want to use some specific character set you can refer to the MySQL manual.

```
ALTER DATABASE <metastore_db_name> CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Once the character set configured, then start the new hive session, will solve your issue.

All the best!!!

Comment: It still doesn't work. My metastore database name is "hive", when I execute "show create database hive", it shows "CREATE DATABASE `hive` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 */". So, the character set is utf8 now. I also restart mysql and hive, but the problem still there.

Comment: "SHOW CREATE TABLE DBS;" what it says in mysql for metastore db?

Comment: | DBS   | CREATE TABLE `DBS` (
  `DB_ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `DESC` varchar(4000) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `DB_LOCATION_URI` varchar(4000) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `NAME` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `OWNER_NAME` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `OWNER_TYPE` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`DB_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |

Comment: Its look like good for me, something is missing. I don't know, but one last suggestion is try to restart the metastore as well.